# Query latest table in the BigQuery dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset containing tables with similar table names ending in yyyymmdd. For example:

```
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140815
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140816
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140817
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140818
...
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140903
myproject:mydataset.Sales20140904
```

Is there any way to write the BigQuery to query the latest table in the dataset (for the above example it is myproject:mydataset.Sales20140904 )?

Answer (score 9):

N.N. answer is good, but relying on the modification date is problematic if an old set of data is reimported that would erroneously be pulled as the "latest"  Since the table_id explicitly lists the dates in the correct order it is best to use that value directly.

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
TABLE_QUERY(MyDATASET, 
      'table_id CONTAINS "MyTable" 
      AND table_id= (Select MAX(table_id) 
                              FROM MyDATASET.__TABLES__
                              where table_id contains "MyTable")'
            )
```

Comment: `table_id = (select max(..) )` always will satisfy condition `table_id contains "MyTable"` so first part is not needed

Answer (score 5):

If you have to use standard dialect (which is highly recommended by BQ Team) it should be something like this

```
#standardSQL
select * from `myproject:mydataset.*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = (select max(_TABLE_SUFFIX) from `myproject:mydataset.*`)
```

One benefit of this that you can also expose table name you query in result

```
#standardSQL
select _TABLE_SUFFIX source, t.* from `myproject:mydataset.*` t
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = (select max(_TABLE_SUFFIX) from `myproject:mydataset.*`)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use Table wildcard function.
If the latest is today's table, use

```
Select * from TABLE_DATE_RANGE(MyDATASET.PREFIX, Current_Timestamp(), Current_Timestamp())
```

If last changed table could be of a past date. you can use:

```
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
    TABLE_QUERY(MyDATASET, 
          'table_id CONTAINS "MyTable" 
          AND last_modified_time= (Select MAX(last_modified_time) 
                                  FROM MyDATASET.__TABLES__
                                  where table_id contains "MyTable")'
                )
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_QUERY(myproject:mydataset,
  "table_id IN (
     SELECT table_id FROM myproject:mydataset.__TABLES__  
     WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^Sales.*")
     ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Only solutions I can think of involve modifications to your daily ETL:

A: update your ETL to create a copy of the latest table once it's been loaded or updated. If you're using bq command line tool that would be something like:

```
bq cp mydataset.Sales20140904 mydataset.SalesLatestDay
```

Then you just query against the SalesLatestDay table.

B: Better yet, create a View  that references your most recent table ( "SELECT * FROM mydataset.Sales20140904" ), and update it daily. Info on creating views using the REST API:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Answer (score 0):

If your table is surely updated daily, here is my trick.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(myproject:mydataset.Sales, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```